# Create table with given data in HTML

Tags: html

everyone! I am quite new to coding and I would like some help. Unfortunately, I don't have any code. Here's what I have to do.

I am given a variable data (similar to a dict in Python) and I have to create a table based on that data. I will leave an example below.

If you need any more info, I will provide.

Thanks!

```
users = 
[
    { 
      "name" : "N0",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D0",
      "car" : "C0"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N1",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D1",
      "car" : "C1"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N2",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D2",
      "car" : "C2"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N3",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D3",
      "car" : "C3"
    }
]
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to add the data to the table dynamically. You can change the `users` value with same format the table will get created automatically.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Car</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
const users = 
[
    { 
      "name" : "N0",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D0",
      "car" : "C0"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N1",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D1",
      "car" : "C1"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N2",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D2",
      "car" : "C2"
    },
    { 
      "name" : "N3",
      "dateOfBirth" : "D3",
      "car" : "C3"
    }
]

users.forEach((element)=>{

$("#myTable").append(`
<tr>
<td>${element.name}</td>
    <td>${element.dateOfBirth}</td>
    <td>${element.car}</td>
 </tr>
`)

})


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that’s exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Example for 2 rows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>A basic HTML table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>dateOfBirth</th>
    <th>car</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N0</td>
    <td>D0</td>
    <td>C0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>To undestand the example better, we have added borders to the table.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/de/html/html_tables.htm

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I know how to create a table, I just wanted to be able to only modify the variable in order to change the table (instead of looking for each element).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to coding rather than finding answers here and there I will suggest you to start learning how to code, Links to "TABLE" lecture is already in your comments please follow that, also for the answer to your question going to write the code below:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DateOfBirth</th>
    <th>Car</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N0</td>
    <td>D0</td>
    <td>C0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N2</td>
    <td>D2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```